# Read tab-delimited data into Hive array

Tags: csv, awk, sed, hive

Data format I need:

```
    12cef8e1b711a351        [1377045694501,1377045728475,1377045709652]
    12cf3cb988f10a87        [1380741459591,1380739871201,1380739785397,1380740303830,1380739849591]
    12d1be8adb90a88b        [1375541238666,1375541281821]
    12d29ba61341e7ce        [1377855844089,1377855785342]
    12d2e28e50d42d19        [1381974506104,1381973579872,1377988785664,1381976074258]
```

Data format I have - everything is tab-delimited:

```
    12cef8e1b711a351      1377045694501       377045728475       1377045709652
    12cf3cb988f10a87      1380741459591       1380739871201      1380739785397     1380740303830     1380739849591
    12d1be8adb90a88b      1375541238666       1375541281821 
    12d29ba61341e7ce      1377855844089       1377855785342 
    12d2e28e50d42d19      1381974506104       1381973579872      1377988785664      1381976074258
```

How do I process tab-delimited data so that the first field is delimited from the rest with tab, and everything else is comma-delimited and surrounded by []. Possibly, each comma-delimited item also has to be concluded into "".

I need to read these data into Hive table

```
  CREATE TABLE id_timestamps (id STRING, timestamps array<STRING>);
```

Can I read it directly to Hive with some tricks or shell I transform tab-delimited data with awk or sed? Please, help with some suggestions and recipes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This awk script produces the desired format:

```
awk '{printf "%s\t[", $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?",":"]\n")}' file
```

Print the first column, followed by a tab character and the opening "[". Print the rest of the columns followed by a ",", except the last, which is followed by a "]" and a newline.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s\t[", $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?",":"]\n")}' file
12cef8e1b711a351        [1377045694501,377045728475,1377045709652]
12cf3cb988f10a87        [1380741459591,1380739871201,1380739785397,1380740303830,1380739849591]
12d1be8adb90a88b        [1375541238666,1375541281821]
12d29ba61341e7ce        [1377855844089,1377855785342]
12d2e28e50d42d19        [1381974506104,1381973579872,1377988785664,1381976074258]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. By the way, in order to load into Hive I used CREATE TABLE ... ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE; I wonder if I could have the same delimiter for FIELDS and COLLECTION? Then I could just skip this step altogether and load into Hive.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Unfortunately, I am not at all familiar with Hive so I don't know how to answer your further question. If you original problem is solved, please consider accepting my answer and upvoting it if you found it useful. If you are stuck with something more specific to Hive, you could then ask a new question.